# Verilog: is connection without wires possible?

Tags: verilog, intel-fpga

I am sorry to ask this question, which I believe is very basic, but I cannot find an answer. The following example clearly works. But I would like to omit the declaration of the wires ay and by.

```
module sub(output reg y);
endmodule

module top(input wire sel,output wire x);
wire ay,by;


sub a(.y(ay));
sub b(.y(by));

assign x= sel ?ay:by;

endmodule
```

Modules have a names. It is possible to address their ports directly? if yes, what is the correct syntax? This does not work (in Quartus)

```
module sub(output reg y);
endmodule

module top(input wire sel,output wire x);


sub a();
sub b();

assign x= sel ?a.y:b.y;

endmodule
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not possible to do this.

The `module.wire` syntax works in some systems, but all the synthesis tools will require you to use the ports properly.

Comment: thank you. what are the instance names used for then? just for reports?

Comment: They're used whenever you need to identify a particular instance, such as in SDC constraints. They get used when exporting to other file formats too.

Answer (score 1):

Wire declarations can be omitted and in most case a 1 bit wide wire will be implied. This is generally considered bad practise as you will end up with width mismatches if you forget to declare those wider than 1 bit.

```
module sub(output reg y);
endmodule

module top(input wire sel,output wire x);
//wire ay,by; No wire declaration

sub a(.y(ay)); //1 bit wide wire implied
sub b(.y(by));

assign x= sel ?ay:by;

endmodule
```

Unconnected outputs will be optimised away by synthesis.

Comment: thank you, however my purpose was omitting the connection in the module instantation.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? any way no you can not and would lead to really bad programming practise. Verilog describes hardware and how it is connected.

Comment: for the same reason that if you have a struct in c you can access its members by structName.member

Comment: but your describing hardware and connectivity not just functionality. Unless your talking about verification of a design then you have different approaches.